# .NET Core Serilog Add username to logs via enrichment or middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, serilog

I am trying to add username to my logs. The documentation shows this:

```
class ThreadIdEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(propertyFactory.CreateProperty(
                "ThreadId", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
    }
}
```

However, I've read somewhere else that I need to use middleware to add the usernames to the logs.

This is what I have so far:

Middleware to get the current users username

```
public class UserNameEnricher 
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public UserNameEnricher(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", context.User.Identity.Name);

        return next(context);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMiddleware<UserNameEnricher>();
```

Program.cs

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
   .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft"))
   .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("System"))
   .Enrich.FromLogContext()
   .CreateLogger();
```

However despite all these configurations, the usernames still aren't appearing. What am I missing?

Serilog Configuration:

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Critical",
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "MSSqlServer",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=App-7661DEE4-C53F-4E49-B140-2AFAA2C85927;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
          "schemaName": "App",
          "tableName": "EventLogs"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add user to the log context when using Serilog and Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896465/add-user-to-the-log-context-when-using-serilog-and-asp-net-core)

Comment: Yeah none of those worked for me.

Comment: you probably need to use `{Properties}` somewhere in a format string ? Have you tried setting a breakpoint and inspecting one of the LogEvents flowing through and/or sending to Seq which always has them. (see http://getseq.net)

Comment: How do I set Properties?

Comment: According to the docs for the MSSqlServer sink, your properties should appear in a `Properties` column in `App.EventLogs` by default.

Comment: @Kirk nothing appears in it so far. I'm not sure what I'm missing also

Comment: Properties is the catch-all token for properties that have been added but not used in messages - Again, highly recommend setting up Seq for local testing to help you learn this stuff (the docs on formatting messages will explain Properties to you better than I can)

Answer (score 3):

For making it work, you need to specify `outputTemplate`.

> Properties from events, including those attached using enrichers, can also appear in the output template.

[Output templates](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#output-templates)

Here is a demo code which is used for `RollingFile`.

```
var output = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message} {ActionName} {UserName} {NewLine}{Exception}";

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
               .Enrich.FromLogContext() // Populates a 'User' property on every log entry
               .WriteTo.RollingFile("Logs/app-{Date}.txt",outputTemplate: output)
               .CreateLogger();
```

**Note**

`{UserName}` in output should map `UserName` in `LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", context.User.Identity.Name);`.

Update:

configure by `appsetting.json`

```
  "Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": "Information",
"Override": {
  "Microsoft": "Critical"
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "RollingFile",
    "Args": {
      "pathFormat": "Logs/app-{Date}.txt",
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message} {UserName} {ActionName}  {NewLine} {Exception}"
    }
  }
]
   }
```

Comment: Hi @Tao Zhou, does this mean that I have to overwrite the current output template with the one in appsettings.json?

Comment: @JianYA Yes, you need to specify where to add the `UserName`.